# Markov/Chebyshev Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking at proofs of Markov or Chebyshev's inequality that for a measurable function, the set $B=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:|f(x)|\ge t\}$            where $0\lt t\lt \infty$  , has a measure that is bounded above by $\frac 1t \int |f|$.  I understand  how this inequality is derived, but my question is, how do you know that the set B is even measurable?  Could there be instances where this set is not measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $B=f^{-1}(A)$ with $A=(-\infty,-t]\cup[t,+\infty)$ and $A$ is closed hence measurable, if $f$ is measurable then $B$ is measurable.